# Android studioでインデントや改行の位置がずれる

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studioでコード整形をかけるとインデントや改行の位置が大幅にずれます
これによってエラーが出るわけではないですが、解決したいので質問しました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: どのように整形されることを期待しているのかを書かないと的確な回答が難しいと思います

Answer (score 1):

1. File メニューから Settings を選んで Settings 画面を表示
2. Editor > Code Style > Java
3. **Use indents relative to expression start** オプションを **OFF**

[image: Settings 画面]

最悪の場合は、Scheme を **Default** に選択すれば、設定全体がデフォルト状態に戻ります。